# how to draw the movement when tracking an object?

Tags: c++, physics

I use webcam and using openCV to retrieve each frame and track object's position.

So basically, I have got one point in each frame. But how can I draw the movement picture in real-time?

Do I need a timer to record several points in certain time and draw lines?

And as in the while loop, I just retrieve one frame, I don't think if I draw a line on this current frame, I could still hold the line in the next frame. So how should I display the movement?

```
while( true )
    {
        //Read the video stream
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        //Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay(frame); // I got a point from this function

        // waitkey enter
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); } 

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a vector to hold positions and then draw them on every frame.
Notice that your function needs to return the detected point. I've changed its name cause it doesn't draw at that point. You can fix that later.

> ```
> vector<CvPoint> trajectory;
> Vec3b mycolor(100,0,0);
>
> while( true )
> {
>     //Read the video stream
>     capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
>     frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
>
>     //Apply the classifier to the frame
>     CvPoint cur_pnt=detect(frame); // I got a point from this function
>     trajectory.push_back(cur_point);
>
>     //Draw points.
>     for (int i=0;i<trajectory.size();i++)
>         frame.at<Vec3b>(trajectory[i].x,trajectory[i].y)=mycolor;
>
>     // waitkey enter
>     int c = waitKey(10);
>     if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); } 
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks! But there's no at function for IplImage, so I change it to:  for(int c=0;c<3;c++){frame->imageData[trajectory[i].y*frame->widthStep+3*trajectory[i].x+c]=255;
    }